# Rotated View's onTouch wrong coordinates

Tags: android, view, ontouch

I must get upside down view w/o moving the System menu. So I do:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().setRotation(180);
```

But all child buttons get onTouch event not when they being touched, but when I touch the areas where they would be without rotation.
How can I fix the problem?

Comment: you need to translate touch events with a matrix as well since you code just rotates the end resulting image of the root view, but not the root view itself.

Comment: Well, I might be misspelling the problem. The Buttons "onTouch" is triggered from the wrong place. That is, I can conert/translate onTouch for the view, but it doesn't even come in play when I do touch on the "original" place...

Comment: Then I think you need to place some view over whole layout, and it should translate touch events. Or do something with the parent layout's intersectTouchEvents

Answer (score 0):

Got solution without translation matrix and such... Just create a new Layout class like this:

```
public class RotatableView extends FrameLayout {

public RotatableView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public RotatableView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    super(context, attributeSet);
    setUpsideDown();
}

private void setUpsideDown() {
    this.setRotation(180);
}
}
```

and use it for your layouts